# 500 error for mobile.stackexchange.com when logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, 500-server-error

When I typed *Stackexchange* into mobile Safari, the Siri suggested site was https://mobile.stackexchange.com but going there produces this error:

```
{"error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"}
```

This site can also be found when Google searching, with this description:

> This is a domain for mobile services for the Stack Exchange network. The non- public services underlying Stack...

This shows that Google can access the page, even if there’s almost nothing there. It seems like I only get the error when I am logged in, no matter the browser or OS.

Can this “mobile” url be fixed to not give an error (and maybe also removed from Google, because it’s not very useful)?

Comment: Well the bug is in Siri, which should not suggest a site that does not exist. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. The 500 error is fixed now.